# Angular-translate function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm including translation to my website using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/)

So I have this piece of code:

```
<td class="nav-button">
        <a  href="{{button.location}}" class ="'{{button.clazz}}'" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails" >
                {{button.text}}
                <div ng-show="button.subButtons.length && showDetails" ng-repeat="subButton in button.subButtons">
                    <a href="{{subButton.location}}" class="'{{button.clazz}}'" translate>
                        {{subButton.text}}
                    </a>
                </div>
        </a>
</td>
```

The sub-buttons appear normally and the translation works just right. But only translating the subButtons.

The problem is : I want to translate the `{{button.text}}` as well

But when I add the translate to the first `<a>`, neither the features works.
I've tried several ways to fix this but I failed.
Somebody that maybe had the same problem could help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

angular translate is a filter

```
{{button.text|translate}}
```

Comment: angular-translate is also a service and a directive...how does that even try to answer his question?

Comment: Wow, It really worked. But why can't I attach the translation to the entire <a> scope ? I did it in other scopes and it worked just fine

Comment: When you dont need to use the directive, use the filter for angular-translate. Always.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to what `subButton.text` contains. It needs to contain the key of the translation value that you are looking for. For example, my translations file looks like this:

```
{
    "SUB_BUTTON": "Hello there, this is the sub button"
}
```

I can create a button in multiple ways.

#### via filter

```
<button>{{"SUB_BUTTON" | translate}}</button>
```

#### via directive 1

```
<button translate="SUB_BUTTON"></button>
```

#### via directive 2

```
<button translate>"SUB_BUTTON"</button>
```

For more info please read further on the [angular-translate Docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translate)

Comment: Yeah the translate file is just like you wrote, and it works in other scopes. The problem is with that scope specifically.
The directives 1 and 2 didn't work, but the filter did